# Flutter add a button to a Grid View

Tags: android, flutter

So I have the following which works however I need to wrap the image in a button so that it is clickable.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 1,
        childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
            (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4), //childAspectRatio: 200,
      ),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: photos.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(photos.data[index].imageurl, width: 80.0, height: 80.0,);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now I know I need to add it to

```
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Image.network(photos.data[index].imageurl, width: 80.0, height: 80.0,);
      },
```

I am wondering it says return which I understand as it will return what it is shown.

So can I put a container and put the image inside the container?

ideally I want to do something like this - not sure if it is best practice:

```
child: new RaisedButton(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                textColor: Colors.white,
                                color: Colors.red,
                                onPressed: () async {  await changestation('http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream');
                                },

                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
                                  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: _"So can I put a container and put the image inside the container?_"  Yes, you can, as long as you are return `Widget`.

Comment: You can use `RaisedButton` here but that will make the image look like a button & you will have to remove its decorations. I would suggest you use `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` widget. @JohnJoe is correct. You can return anything that is `Widget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return Image` is not returning a `Image` it is returning a `Widget`, here we can able to return `Image` because `Image` extends `Widget`, essentially making it a `Widget`(OOP right),
We can nest Widgets doesn't matter which, A Container can have Container as a child, even a Button can Have Scaffold as its child or even a MaterialApp!! (Given the constraints meets requirement),

**Therefore** you can wrap the `Image` inside a GestureDetector (Which is a Widget) and pass a function to the `onTap` property.